# Important genes beyond PAM50 for breast cancer classification

Tags: gene, cancer, deep-learning

*Note: this question has also been asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9471832/)*

I am currently trying to complete a Breast Cancer Classification task using Neural Networks. I have experimented with using my full dataset of gene expressions(1000+) and managed to improve my results by using only the PAM50 genes. I was wondering though what other genes I could add to the list to even better improve my results.

I have tried looking for papers about extending the PAM50, but could not find anything. I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [CSV table](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5921990/bin/12885_2018_4388_MOESM2_ESM.csv) in [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5921990/) with 33 sets of genes.